# What does it mean umelubashot be Col Reqieem

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, chasidut-hasidism, chabad, tanya, baal-hatanya

In Shaar Yichud ch1 of Tanya he says תיבות
ואותיות אלו הן נצבות ועומדות לעולם בתוך רקיע השמים ומלובשות בתוך כל הרקיעים

What does it mean umelubashot beToch kol HarekiIm what specifically is clothed inside?

I know it is the energy although is there more explanation of this in earlier books than the Tanya or after?